# Multi-input single output regression using Scikit neural networks MLPRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network, non-linear-regression

I have a 2D-array data as follows (with M & C as independent variables):

**Data**
[image]

I'm trying to model this regression (f(M,C) = y) using the Scikit MLPRegressor. Not knowing how to go about modeling multivariable input, I tried modeling it as two independent single-input problems. How do I use this output to predict the curve for C=2.3, for example? If anyone can suggest a more elegant way to program this problem, I'd be thankful.

[image]

**Code**

```
# importing module
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

# reading CSV file
#data = read_csv("data\Ex2.csv")
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[2,4.28,5.65],[3,10.04,15.59],[4,18.38,32],[5,29.36,55.90],[6,43.06,88.18],[7,59.52,129.64],[8,78.79,181.02],[9,100.90,243],[10,125.89,316.22]], columns=['M','C=2.1','C=2.5'])

# converting column data to list
M = data['M'].values
C1 = data['C=2.1'].values
C2 = data['C=2.5'].values
C = np.column_stack((C1,C2))

M = M.reshape(M.shape[0],-1)

for i in range(0, 2):

    Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(M, C[:,i], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)            
    mlp = MLPRegressor(random_state=42, activation='relu', hidden_layer_sizes=(100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,8))    
    
    mlp.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain.ravel())    
    Yguess = mlp.predict(Xtest)
    Y = mlp.predict(M)
    
    #plt.plot(Xtest[:,0], Ytest, '.')
    #plt.plot(Xtest[:,0], Yguess, 'r.')
    plt.plot(M, C[:,i], 'o')
    plt.plot(M, Y, 'r')
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Where is your `data = read_csv("data\Ex2.csv")`? Adding your input data

Comment: to be fair, this is a pretty good start so far. The question is how do you wish to compute the values for `c=2.3`. do you intend for it to be some kind of weighted average between `c=2.1` and `c=2.5` and if so what are the weightings ?

Comment: the contents of the file Ex2.csv is given at the beginning of the question. Its the 2D table with M & C as variables

Comment: @RonnieIndia please add this `DataFrame` then we can run your code

Comment: @l'mahdi    data = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[2,4.28,5.65],[3,10.04,15.59],[4,18.38,32],[5,29.36,55.90],[6,43.06,88.18],[7,59.52,129.64],[8,78.79,181.02],[9,100.90,243],[10,125.89,316.22]], columns=['M','C=2.1','C=2.5'])

Comment: @D.L     I'd want the model to predict the values for c=2.3

Comment: @RonnieIndia,  are you asking how to use a particular model or are you asking the general question of what model to use ?

Comment: @D.L  The problem I'm trying to solve is something like this:  For C=2.1 and for C=2.5, the variation of the output (y) vs M is known. How do I use this data to predict the output vs M for C=2.3 or for C=3.0 or so on...I got stuck halfway through the solution. Not sure how to proceed from hereon

Comment: @RonnieIndia, do you want do this only with scikit-learn?

Comment: @l'mahdi  I'd prefer to solve it using scikit-learn. I'd move to other packages only as a last resort.

Comment: is there a specific model in `scikit-learn` that you are trying to implement ?

Comment: @D.L ...not sure about the question. I'm using the neural network function MLPRegressor in the code.

Comment: okay,  so you will be most likely implementing `multi layer perception`:   https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_partial_dependence.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-inspection-plot-partial-dependence-py

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about DL theory and/or methodology - please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem as below. Thank you @l'mahdi for your help and to @D.L for your comments

**Code solution**

```
# importing module
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

# reading CSV file
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[2,4.28,5.65],[3,10.04,15.59],[4,18.38,32],[5,29.36,55.90],[6,43.06,88.18],[7,59.52,129.64],[8,78.79,181.02],[9,100.90,243],[10,125.89,316.22]], columns=['M','C=2.1','C=2.5'])

# converting column data to array
M = data['M'].values
C1 = data['C=2.1'].values
C2 = data['C=2.5'].values

C = np.concatenate((C1,C2))
I = np.full_like(M,1)
MC1 = np.column_stack((M,I*2.1))
MC2 = np.column_stack((M,I*2.5))
MC3 = np.column_stack((M,I*2.4))
MC = np.concatenate((MC1,MC2))

MC = MC.reshape(MC.shape[0],-1)

mlp = MLPRegressor(random_state=0, activation='relu', hidden_layer_sizes=(100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,8))    

mlp.fit(MC,C)  
Y = mlp.predict(MC3)
    
plt.plot(M, C1)
plt.plot(M, C2)
plt.plot(M, Y, 'r')
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You need Recurrent Neural Network(RNN) or Long short-term memory(LSTM), you can solve your problem with `tensorflow` like below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[2,4.28,5.65],
                     [3,10.04,15.59],[4,18.38,32],
                     [5,29.36,55.90],[6,43.06,88.18],
                     [7,59.52,129.64],[8,78.79,181.02],
                     [9,100.90,243],[10,125.89,316.22]], 
                    columns=['M','C=2.1','C=2.5']) 
arr = data.values[:, 1:]
arr = np.insert(arr, 0, [2.1 , 2.5], axis=0).T
arr = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, 3, axis=1)

X_train = arr[...,:-1]
y_train = arr[..., -1]
X_train = X_train.reshape([-1,2])
y_train = y_train.ravel()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(200, input_shape=(2,1), activation='tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=16)

X_test = np.array([[2.3,1]], dtype=np.float64)
res = []
for _ in range(10):
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    X_test = np.append(X_test, y_pred[0][0])[1:][None,...]
    res.append(y_pred[0][0])

# predict res for 2.3 => [4.725103, 10.564905, 19.61012, 30.361404, 43.3811, 60.815994, 86.90681, 118.34455, 154.1196, 181.1613]


M = data['M'].values
C1 = data['C=2.1'].values
C2 = data['C=2.5'].values
C = np.column_stack((C1,C2))
M = M.reshape(M.shape[0],-1)

for i in range(0, 2):
    plt.plot(M, C[:,i])
plt.plot(res)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
...
Epoch 999/1000
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 13.2078
Epoch 1000/1000
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 13.0156
```

[image]

Comment: @l'mahdi   Thank you! This looks similar to what I'm targeting at. Let me try to understand the code as some of the parts are new to me and get back.

Comment: @RonnieIndia, welcome. if this is what you want, please edit your question and say you accept other approach or method and no problem if answer will be without scikit-learn.

Comment: @RonnieIndia, please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @l'mahdi  There seems to be a discrepancy in the logic used. Nevertheless, your solution was useful. So I marked it up. I was able to solve the problem using scikit-learn  which I'll post soon